# Assembly x86 - status code not shown as defined

Tags: assembly, x86, ld, gnu-assembler

I have this code I've written in Assembly x86:

```
.section .data
  list: .long 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0
.section .text
.globl _start

_start:
  movl $0,%eax # eax will save our current location
  movl list(,%eax,4),%edi
  movl %edi,%ebx # ebx will save the biggest number since it's the beginning - edi is the biggest

cmpLoop:
  cmp $0,%edi
  je printBiggestNum

  incl %eax
  movl list(,%eax,4), %edi
  cmp %ebx,%edi
  jg setNewBiggestNum

setNewBiggestNum:
  movl %edi,%ebx
  jmp cmpLoop

printBiggestNum:
  movl $1,%eax
  int $0x80
```

As you can see, at the end of the function `printBiggestNum`, `%ebx` should already be equal to $5, and because it's also the register that determines the status code - the status code should be 5 too. But the fact is that the status code is 0. If I'm adding the line:
`movl $5,%ebx`
It of course works.

I cannot determine why this is happening and I would love to hear your solution for that.

(Also it's important to mention that I debugged this code (with `gdb`) and it really doing 5 loops and then calling the function `printBiggestNum` and exits after that, so no way it returns back after that or something like that).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: When I single-step debugged your code (with this not-very-minimal example that only shows the bug on the last iteration), I saw that `movl %edi,%ebx` ran on the last iteration, setting EBX to 0.  Then I looked at the `jg` and noticed that it doesn't skip the `mov`, it either jumps to or falls through to the `mov` so it runs either way.  Thus a duplicate, see the link at the top of the page.

Comment: @PeterCordes. Hey, I don't know if it's the right place for that but you're looking very experienced and I would like some help. I am wondering how did you managed to single-step debug it with the ability to see the registers values at each step. Also how do you recommend me to search for it in the next time I'll need help because I really didn't managed to get to the question you mentioned above when I searched for it... Also I would like any reading or learning material that is related to this topic so next time I could do better... Thank you very much for the help and for your time!

Comment: See the section at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info - there are some links to Q&As that explain how to do that using GDB `layout reg` and `stepi`.  (Or `display $ebx` to have it print something on every single step if TUI mode isn't working.)  Or use any GUI debugger (many are a front-end for GDB or LLDB).  Or there are some mods for GDB that use its scripting language to build a fancier UI in it.

Comment: As for how I found that duplicate, I knew that specific question existed, and typed "executes condition wrong" into my browser's location bar for it to auto-complete it.  It's also linked from the x86 tag wiki, or google could have found it by title. For you to find it yourself, you'd already have to have found the bug (that a branch was "ignoring" your condition) and hopefully reduced your program to a [mcve].  There's a good chance you'd have already figured out why it was happening after narrowing it down to that, in which case you wouldn't need to search.